# Blend mode multiply for whole window on macOS with Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

For a very specific use case I need a window multiplied on top of every other window, playing a video and not receiving mouse events. Everything works so far, except multiplying the window on top of the background, is that even possible? I tried it with various combinations of Visual Effect Views, but can't get quite the effect as if you would set the blend mode of a layer in Photoshop to multiply.

Comment: NSVisualEffectView has the blending option .behindWindow so it seems possible, but as far as I know CALayer with CIFilters only work within the same view hierarchy.